# React server rending got a warning.React attempted to reuse markup

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Here is my code of component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import NavbarStore from '../stores/NavbarStore';
import NavbarActions from '../actions/NavbarActions';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = NavbarStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    NavbarStore.listen(this.onChange);
    NavbarActions.getCharacterCount();

    let socket = io.connect();

    socket.on('onlineUsers', (data) => {
      NavbarActions.updateOnlineUsers(data);
    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(() => {
      NavbarActions.updateAjaxAnimation('fadeIn');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        NavbarActions.updateAjaxAnimation('fadeOut');
      }, 750);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NavbarStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let searchQuery = this.state.searchQuery.trim();

    if (searchQuery) {
      NavbarActions.findCharacter({
        searchQuery: searchQuery,
        searchForm: this.refs.searchForm,
        history: this.props.history
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
        <div className='navbar-header'>
          <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbar'>
            <span className='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
            <span className='icon-bar'></span>
            <span className='icon-bar'></span>
            <span className='icon-bar'></span>
          </button>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-brand'>
            <span className={'triangles animated ' + this.state.ajaxAnimationClass}>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
              <div className='tri'></div>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
              <div className='tri'></div>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
              <div className='tri'></div>
              <div className='tri invert'></div>
            </span>
            NEF
            <span className='badge badge-up badge-danger'>{this.state.onlineUsers}</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div id='navbar' className='navbar-collapse collapse'>
          <form ref='searchForm' className='navbar-form navbar-left animated' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <div className='input-group'>
              <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder={this.state.totalCharacters + ' characters'} defaultValue={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={NavbarActions.updateSearchQuery} />
              <span className='input-group-btn'>
                <button className='btn btn-default' onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}><span className='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
          <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/stats'>Stats</Link></li>
            <li className='dropdown'>
              <a href='#' className='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Top 100 <span className='caret'></span></a>
              <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                <li><Link to='/top'>Top Overall</Link></li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/top/caldari'>Caldari</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/top/caldari/achura'>Achura</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/caldari/civire'>Civire</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/caldari/deteis'>Deteis</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/top/gallente'>Gallente</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/top/gallente/gallente'>Gallente</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/gallente/intaki'>Intaki</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/gallente/jin-mei'>Jin-Mei</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/top/minmatar'>Minmatar</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/top/minmatar/brutor'>Brutor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/minmatar/sebiestor'>Sebiestor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/minmatar/vherokior'>Vherokior</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/top/amarr'>Amarr</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/top/amarr/amarr'>Amarr</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/amarr/ni-kunni'>Ni-Kunni</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/top/amarr/khanid'>Khanid</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='divider'></li>
                <li><Link to='/shame'>Hall of Shame</Link></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li className='dropdown'>
              <a href='#' className='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Female <span className='caret'></span></a>
              <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                <li><Link to='/female'>All</Link></li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/female/caldari'>Caldari</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/female/caldari/achura'>Achura</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/caldari/civire/'>Civire</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/caldari/deteis'>Deteis</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/female/gallente'>Gallente</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/female/gallente/gallente'>Gallente</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/gallente/intaki'>Intaki</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/gallente/jin-mei'>Jin-Mei</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/female/minmatar'>Minmatar</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/female/minmatar/brutor'>Brutor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/minmatar/sebiestor'>Sebiestor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/minmatar/vherokior'>Vherokior</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/female/amarr'>Amarr</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/female/amarr/amarr'>Amarr</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/amarr/ni-kunni'>Ni-Kunni</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/female/amarr/khanid'>Khanid</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li className='dropdown'>
              <a href='#' className='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Male <span className='caret'></span></a>
              <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                <li><Link to='/male'>All</Link></li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/male/caldari'>Caldari</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/male/caldari/achura'>Achura</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/caldari/civire'>Civire</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/caldari/deteis'>Deteis</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/male/gallente'>Gallente</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/male/gallente/gallente'>Gallente</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/gallente/intaki'>Intaki</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/gallente/jin-mei'>Jin-Mei</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/male/minmatar'>Minmatar</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/male/minmatar/brutor'>Brutor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/minmatar/sebiestor'>Sebiestor</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/minmatar/vherokior'>Vherokior</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className='dropdown-submenu'>
                  <Link to='/male/amarr'>Amarr</Link>
                  <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><Link to='/male/amarr/amarr'>Amarr</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/amarr/ni-kunni'>Ni-Kunni</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/male/amarr/khanid'>Khanid</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><Link to='/add'>Add</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

I'm using react server rending.

```
<input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder={this.state.totalCharacters + ' characters'} defaultValue={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={NavbarActions.updateSearchQuery} />
```

The question is when i added placeholder in INPUT element.

**Client result:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0 characters" value=""
          data-reactid="25">
```

**Server result:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0 characters" class="form-control" value=""
          data-reactid="25">
```

And then i got a warning message:

> "Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the
>   checksum was invalid.

This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:↵ (client) >

How to fix it? thanks!

evn:
react@15.0.1
react-router@2.0
nodejs

Answer (score 0):

When I remove placeholder attr. It works fine.